# Error while loading emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

The Error dialog box shows the following error:

> The adb binary found is obsolete and has serious performance problems
>   with the android emulator.

Comment: try to delete and create it again.

Comment: Check you sdk, update it and create a new emulator

Comment: Please download the latest sdk and create a new emulator. I would suggest you to use genymotion which is a lightweight emulator for android.

Comment: Updated sdk and now it works well. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240223/adb-exe-is-obsolete-and-has-serious-performance-problems