# ADB.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems ( New )

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

Im trying to run my application in an emulator but im getting this error; `The ADB binary at C:\Users\siviw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems with the Android Emulator. Please update to a newer version to get significantly faster app / file transfer`

Ive tried to update `SDK Build-Tools` as this post shows; [ADB.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240223/adb-exe-is-obsolete-and-has-serious-performance-problems) but i just keep getting the same result.

How would i go about fixing this error?

Answer (score 4):

In my case I've followed all the instructions I've found on Internet without any luck. Finally I've decided to remove and install again the "SDK Build-Tools" (additional steps 5,6,7,8) and the problem was solved.

1. Menu Tools | SDK Manager
2. Click the second tab "SDK Tools".
3. Check "[x] Show Package Details" in the lower right corner
4. Scroll to the last item under "SDK Build-Tools"(Mine was [x] 28.0.3)
5. Uncheck [ ] 28.0.3
6. Click "Apply"
7. Check [x] 28.0.3
8. Click "Apply"
9. In the dialogue box that pops up, click "OK"
10. When the installer finishes, click "Finish"

Answer (score 0):

Download ADB.exe (you can google it) and paste into this folder.

```
C:\Users\siviw\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\
```

I have faced the same problem. After doing this, my problem has been solved.