# Android Studio says "ADB.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems" although SDK tools says everything is up to date

Tags: android, adb

Popup message: *"ADB.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problem"*

My problem is basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240223/adb-exe-is-obsolete-and-has-serious-performance-problems) and some other similar questions, but none of those answers worked for me.

I tried updating SDK tools but they are already up to date.
I tried removing SDK tools and Apply then re-add then Apply, did not work neither.
I tried adding a new virtual device but same popup appeared.

Comment: Can you run `adb version` on your command line and respond with the output.  Im wondering if your adb version in your path is different than the one being used by Android Studio.  I'm thinking maybe download ADB as a standalone executable and swap it with the one being used by the Android Studio

Comment: Also please post what version your Android SDK Build-Tools is.  It should be Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 for the latest stable I believe

Comment: There's no way to fix this, except in an "upcoming release". Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

The problem in my case was that I had several versions of the **Android SDK Build Tools** installed. To ensure that only the latest one was chosen by the emulator, I had to uncheck the older versions on the SDK Manager. So:

1 - On Android Studio, open the SDK Manager

2 - click the second tab "SDK Tools"

3 - Check "[x] Show Package Details" in the lower right corner

[image]

4 - Make sure that all the versions of Build tools, but the most recent, are unchecked

[image]

5 - Click on the Apply button.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrading manually

Since you already tried the information you linked to in the original posts you can try to upgrade your build tools manually.  On most standard installations your build tools are located at the following directory `%AppData%\..\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools`, and you can download the most recent build tools from google at `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r28.0.3-windows.zip`.

Please do the following

1. Navigate to `%AppData%\..\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools`
2. Check to see what version your folder says.  If it doesn't say 28.X then
3. Download your build tools from `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r28.0.3-windows.zip`
4. Replace the **contents** of the child directory under the build-tools directory with the **contents** inside the downloaded zip's parent folder
5. Restart Android studio

> Before replacing anything make sure you take a backup of the entire build-tools directory to prevent breaking anything further

## Upgrade Automation

Although you claim you tried this, inside android studio you should be able to go to Help -> Check For Updates.  This should tell you if all your tools are up to date and is the preferred way to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Chris , I had installed the SDK in a different location other that the default one you mentioned just in case  I have to reinstall my operating system I don't have to worry about the downloaded SDK as they are huge and I don't want to download all this again.

Will this make a difference in the steps you advised (other that the obvious step of substituting %AppData% by my non-default path, e.g.  "E:\..."

I'm telling that also because someone may advise that using a non-default path may cause this problem I'm having.