# I want to know how to update adb.exe using command prompt if possible,

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

when I am using android studio and running the emulator it works but gives me a message that adb.exe at the sdk location needs to be updated and it has a serious performance problems
I tried to go to SDK manager and tools and downloaded the last SDK build tools 29.0.0.rc2 and deleted the emulator and made a new one but it is still giving the same message, also i tried to download SDK build tools which are compatible with the emulator API but it also still rising the same message.

> The ADB binary found at C:\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems with the Android Emulator. Please update to a newer version to get significantly faster app/file transer.

[Here is a picture showing the exact message/error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnCB2.png)

Comment: Adb in Android studio comes by default with SDK manager. If you want latest version go to Android studio update it will show you the updates available and download it. Read more about Adb here - https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: Welcome aboard! Questions wont stand a chance to receive a good answer when they are being written poorly detailed and not outright. Your question needs more clarifications and at least, dumped error of your adb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240223/adb-exe-is-obsolete-and-has-serious-performance-problems)