# The ADB binary is obsolete and has serious performance problems with the Android Emulator (error)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

Android Studio produces the following error:

> The ADB binary at
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe is
>   obsolete and has serious performance problems with the Android
>   Emulator. Please update to a newer version to get significantly faster
>   app / file transfer

I tried to check at: SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Android SDK Build-Tools ([link to that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51549901/12700911)). But the last update has been installed already.

P.S. I know, such a question already exists ([link to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240223/adb-exe-is-obsolete-and-has-serious-performance-problems)), but there I can't write a solution that helped me, because I don't have enough reputation points. So, I'll write here the solution, maybe it will help someone...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Android Studio should recheck SDK (it should help, at least it helped me)

Go to:

> SDK Manager -> Android SDK Location: (Edit) -> Next -> Next -> Finish

SDK Location doesn't have to be changed.

Answer (score 7):

1. Open SDK Manager
2. Click on --> SDK Tools.
3. Check--> Show Package Details. (Look at the bottom right corner)
4. Under--> SDK Build-Tools, scroll to the bottom and check the last item. (when I checked it was 19.1.0)
5. Click on--> Apply.
6. A dialog box appears just click OK.
7. It begins to install.
8. After installation gets completed just click--> Finish.

Comment: Wow. Warning is gone and emulated devices started to boot faster after this. Ubuntu 20.04.1, Android Studio 4.1.1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in short, I also have that problem.  I accidentally solved by switching the graphic card from Integrated to Dedicated Graphics Card on my laptop setting.  That is it, no more error pop up.

in long, I was trying to the get the emulator run faster and less lag.  I am using Android Studio 4 with Win 10 on lenovo notebook with Intel and AMD Graphics Card.  I accidentally found this switching GPU method and it's work for me.  I don't know why or how it is related to adb.exe. I tried to switch back and forth GPU several time to confirm it already.

Give it a try and kindly let me and other knows
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling with the SDK manager did not work for me.
Changing the emulator device Graphics from Automatic to Hardware fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me
Using Android studio 4.2+
**For Windows**
go to File->Settings->Tools->Emulator->Tick 'Launch in a tool window' (option)
Apply
For Mac OS
Preferences->Tools->Emulator->Tick 'Launch in a tool window' (option)
Apply
[Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaVyg.png)