# "the adb binary found at [location] is obsolete and has serious performance issues" but the emulator RUNS!! after displaying the message

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, adb

I know there are many answers online relating to this but I posted this question because none worked.

[image]I have encountered this error but my SDK build-tools are already updated and most importantly when clicking the play button. I get the error that "unable to locate adb" but then the emulator starts and I get the message that the "adb binary found is obsolete..." and still I have the emulator running. How do I solve these 2 adb issues?

I just started today and I am facing a lot of issues.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please check my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709000/the-adb-binary-is-obsolete-and-has-serious-performance-problems-with-the-android/67979513#67979513

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed Android Studio 4.0.1 and had this issue developing Flutter Apps. The solution from **diablolik** in [Configure Android SDK](https://flutterforum.co/t/display-of-please-configure-android-sdk/1252) solved my problem.

I entered into File -> Project Structure:

[Image with blank project SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnFzJ.png)

I changed it and located my SDK location path and it worked: mine was

> D:\SDKs\AndroidSDK